# Binding a ContentView's BindingContext does not update controls inside

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

My binding:

```
<local:MyContentView BindingContext="{Binding Source={x:Reference Root}, Path=BindingContext.Entity.Recipe, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

The BindingContext on the ContentView is being updated when Recipe is changed, but the controls inside MyContentView aren't populating with data. If Recipe is a valid value initially the controls inside MyContentView is populated with the data, but if Recipe starts off as null and is changed to a valid target the controls will not update despite the BindingContext changing.

Comment: You might wanna add the code for MyContentView otherwise we would just be speculating

Comment: The controls bind correctly when the ContentView's BindingContext is initially set to a valid object. The problem is when the ContentView's BindingContext changes the controls are not populated with the new object's data.

Controls are simply binding to the BindingContext like so:

`Text="{Binding Name}"`

Comment: Then there is something wrong with the new `BindingContext`!!

Answer (score 0):

according to your description, you want to bind contentview in contentpage,  the data don't update when data source changed, I guess that you may don't implement **INotifypropertychanged** for Recipe, you can follow then following article to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-binding/

Another way ti to use **Bindableproperty**, I do one sample for you, you can take a look:

Contentview:

```
<ContentView.Content>
  <StackLayout>
        <Label x:Name="label1" Text="{Binding Text}" />

    </StackLayout>
```

```
public partial class mycontenview : ContentView
{


    public static BindableProperty TextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
propertyName: "Text",
returnType: typeof(string),
declaringType: typeof(mycontenview),
defaultValue: string.Empty,
defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWay,
propertyChanged: HandlePropertyChanged);


    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(TextProperty, value);
        }
    }
    private static void HandlePropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        mycontenview contentview = bindable as mycontenview;
        contentview.label1.Text = newValue.ToString();

    }


    public mycontenview()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
}
```

MainPage:

```
<StackLayout>
    <Label Text="welcome to xamarin world!"/>
    <Button x:Name="btn1" Text="btn1" Clicked="btn1_Clicked"/>
    <local:mycontenview  Text="{Binding str}"/>
</StackLayout>

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private string _str;
    public string str
    {
        get { return _str; }
        set
        {
            _str = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("str");
        }
    }
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        m = new model1() { str = "test 1", str1 = "test another 1" };
        str = "cherry";
        this.BindingContext = this;
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;



    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs((propertyName)));
    }



    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(storage, value))
        {
            return false;
        }
        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);



        return true;
    }



    private void btn1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        str = "this is test!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello! It does implement INotifyPropertyChanged. I said in the post that the ContentView's BindingContext - which is binded directly to the Recipe - changes correctly. However, the controls inside the ContentView does not update when the BindingContext changes.

I'm not sure your example is what I'm trying to do - I'm trying to bind the ContentView's BindingContext to a specific property so, when the BindingContext changes, the controls inside it are also updated.

Comment: @Kyle M, Can you provide one simple sample that can reproduce this issue at github, I will download it and test it.